# How to rotate image about z axis in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to rotate image clockwise

http://jsfiddle.net/eYdjW/

Can we rotate like that given image when 1 to 15 in month as in date picker ..?

```
var rotation = function (){
   $("img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation
   });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    rotation();
});
```

Can we rotate image about z index

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a date picker-like control that only shows at most 3 values at a time, it's not necessary to actually rotate around the z-axis. You can just use vertical animation to move the rendered values up and down, the lower and upper images being behind a fixed gradient shading. If you need to show half of the possible values (say 5 of 10 values), then it would look much better to vertically compress images as their distance from the center increases... But I'm not sure it's worth the effort.